# Git PUSH works for Tortoise but no for Egit, Gerrit repo being used. All default parameters. How to make it work for both?

Tags: git, gerrit, egit

I am getting a pretty weird error here.

I can clone and push changes to a GIT Gerrit repository using Tortoise GIT, but if I try to do the same using eclipse eGit, I can clone the repository, but when I try to push the changes I get this error

```
Repository http://xyz@devops-gerrit.xyz.com/gerrit/abc

cannot upload review
Branch refs/heads/master:
You need 'Push' rights to upload code review requests.
Verify that you are pushing to the right branch.
User: xyz
Please read the documentation and contact an administrator
if you feel the configuration is incorrect

Processing changes: refs: 1
Processing changes: refs: 1, done
```

My feeling is that eGit is having some authentication problem, because I am using just the same user and password and repository. It works for Tortoise, so I think it's not the "push rights".

http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Gerrit_Configuration seems not to have any useful information.

Comment: Gerrit rejects a push like `git push origin master:master`. It may allow `git push origin master:refs/for/master`. The former is a direct push that skips code-review. As Gerrit is used to do code-reviews in most cases, the push rights to `refs/heads/*` branches are not granted. You could check what the refspec is in Egit's push command.

Comment: What I did was to clone the repository using tortoise and using eclipse to manage the code. So eGit is using the same git configuration as tortoise (I guess). My understanding here is that Gerrit is rejecting a push from eGit but not from Tortoise, despite they're using the same git configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The error message shows the issue. You're pushing to "refs/**heads**/master" instead of "refs/**for**/master". You don't have permission to push to "refs/heads/master" which would perform a direct push to the branch master bypassing the coding review process.

You need to look at the EGit configuration and the details of how you are executing the push command to figure out why you're pushing to "refs/heads" instead of "refs/for".

Comment: This may help to configure EGit to push to Gerrit: https://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2014/03/07/how-to-get-the-push-to-gerrit-action-back-with-egit/

Comment: my feeling is that egit has something like this in the code "if server == gerrit then check for permission to send gerrit notes too" because the user MAY want to save notes too. However, I am not, thus it's failing.